# How can I handle browser tab restore?

Tags: javascript, browser-tab

The browser tab is closed and then restored using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

I need to execute some logic at the moment when tab is closing or is restored.
But I shouldn't handle navigation to other page, so events like `beforeunload` are not ok.

It's guaranteed that application is not open in more than one tab.

How can I implement this?

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524332/178988)